# Deployment of AppxPackage with Octopus Deploy results in

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-store-apps, octopus-deploy

I am trying to resolve in issue in deploying a package with Octopus Deploy and remote Powershell on a Windows 10 device.

> Executing script on 'HP X2 Martijn' May 23rd 2017 14:54:12 Info
>   Installing new package May 23rd 2017 14:54:12 Info
>   C:\Temp\Octo\HNLHorApp\\lib\*\ May 23rd 2017 14:54:12 Info
>   C:\Temp\Octo\HNLHorApp\lib\CompanyName.AppPackage.Win8_2017.5.23.1_x86_Test\Heineken.Horeca.Win8_2017.5.23.1_x86.appx
>   May 23rd 2017 14:54:12 Info
>   C:\Temp\Octo\HNLHorApp\lib\CompanyName.AppPackage.Win8_2017.5.23.1_x86_Test\Dependencies\x86\Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.12.00.appx May 23rd 2017 14:54:23 Error Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with
>   HRESULT: 0x80073CF6, Package could not be registered. May 23rd 2017
>   14:54:23 Error error 0x80070005: Adding a tile failed with unexpected
>   error. May 23rd 2017 14:54:23 Error NOTE: For additional information,
>   look for [ActivityId] ec8b2896-d3b5-0002-1b17-8cecb5d3d201 in the
>   Event Log or use th May 23rd 2017 14:54:23 Error e command line
>   Get-AppxLog -ActivityID ec8b2896-d3b5-0002-1b17-8cecb5d3d201 May 23rd
>   2017 14:54:23 Error At C:\Octopus\Work\20170523125410-22\Script.ps1:17
>   char:30  May 23rd 2017 14:54:23 Error + ... criptblock
>   {Add-AppxPackage $appx.FullName -DependencyPath $appxDepen ... May
>   23rd 2017 14:54:23 Error +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ May 23rd
>   2017 14:54:23 Error + CategoryInfo          : WriteError:
>   (C:\Temp\Octo\HN...5.23.1_x86.appx:String) [Add-AppxPackage],
>   IOException May 23rd 2017 14:54:23 Error + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
>   May 23rd 2017 14:54:23 Error  May 23rd 2017 14:54:23 Fatal The remote
>   script failed with exit code 1

The command that we run is:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Add-AppxPackage $appx.FullName -DependencyPath $appxDependency.FullName }
```

Does anyone have clue? Because I am really out of options here.

Comment: well, it fails adding a tile, are you confident this works outside of the powershell cmdlet? i don't the PS is the culprit

Comment: Yes, we can install it manually without any issues. It fails on the dependency, but we don't have a clue why it is happening. Locally it runs very smooth, but when using PowerShell it fails.

Comment: is it running as the system?

Comment: No it runs as domain account with local administrator permissions. The same account I use to login. To validate if it runs smoothly